# Match all strings preceding string in brackets

Tags: regex, vba

I'm trying to retrieve preceding `TableNames` before brackets:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(RepositoriesQ[ContentRepository];MATCH(1&2;RepositoriesQ[Url]&RepositoriesQ[Credentials];0));"something")
```

I found the way of getting all strings between brackets:

```
\[(.*?)\]
```

but what i want to get is all strings preceding column names in brackets.
So as result i should get 3 matches here:

```
RepositoriesQ[ContentRepository]
RepositoriesQ[Url]
RepositoriesQ[Credentials]
```

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/5hWHcs/1

Comment: If you need more help please update the question or drop a comment below my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```js
\w+\[[^\][]*]
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/b19Ay9/1). Details:

- `\w+` - one or more word chars
- `\[` - a `[` char
- `[^\][]*` - zero or more chars other than `[` and `]`
- `]` - a `]` char.